# How to organize GraphQL resolver for additional fields

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Let's say I have a simple GraphQL type for a user:

```
type User {
 id: ID!
 name: String!
}

Query {
  user(id:ID!)
}
```

and a resolver

```js
user = (_, {id}, {api})=> api.getUser(id)
```

Now I have add a new field to the `User` called friends and added a new resolver for the `User.friends` field.

```js
friends = ({id}, _, {api})=> api.getFriends(id)
```

So now I wonder when we made a query like this, how can I prevent the call to `api.getUser` but only call `api.getFriends`.

```
query {
  user(id){
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding is that having a resolver defined for the `user` field in the `Query` type, it will always call this resolver first and after that all resolvers for fields in the `User` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem and there is for example this solution out there: https://github.com/gajus/graphql-lazyloader
Check out the README of the project for a structured description of your problem.

Alternatively, you can implement your own class that contains a cached value making use of how GraphQL.js implements default resolvers:

```js
class User {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  getInstance({ api }) {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = api.getUser(this.id);
    }
    return this.instance;
  }

  // notice how id is already a property of this class

  name(args, ctx) {
    return this.getInstance(ctx).then(instance => instance.name);
  }

  // do the same for other fields, user will only be fetched once.

  friends(args, { api }) {
    return api.getFriends(this.id);
  }
}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: (args) => new User(args.id),
  }
}
```

If you use dataloader you can even do this with even less code thanks to caching in dataloader:

```js
// You probably have this function already somewhere in your apollo server creation
function createContext({ api }) {
  return {
    api,
    loaders: {
      user: new Dataloader((ids) => ids.map(id => api.getUser(id))),
    },
  }
}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: (parent, args) => ({ id: args.id }),
  },
  User: {
    name: ({ id }, args, { loaders }) =>
      loaders.user.load(id).then(user => user.name),
    otherProp: ({ id }, args, { loaders }) =>
      loaders.user.load(id).then(user => user.otherProp),
    friends: ({ id }, args, { api })=> api.getFriends(id),
  }
}
```

Dataloader will, even when called twice, only reach to the API once. An added benefit is, that it will cache the value. Ideally, you even provide a batch load function in the API to make the loader even more efficient.

Be aware, that `user.fields.name` now makes calls for every friend to the API. To avoid that, you could check if the property exists:

```js
    name: (parent, args, { loaders }) =>
      parent.name ?? loaders.user.load(parent.id).then(user => user.name),
```